# Editing your code and seeing difference without recompiling

Tags: c, debugging, runtime, sdl, edit

I saw more than once people changing code like [Notch does in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BES9EKK4Aw4), where he edits the source code and, without recompiling it, the changes get into the game.

Right now I'm doing a extended Pong version in C with SDL2 and need this function to edit some variables into the game. Is so tiring to compile, run and go to the edited part of the game every time I do a tiny edit on the source code. What is the name of this technique and how do I do this in my code?

Comment: Looks like he's running the program in debug mode and changing values in memory through the debugger.

Comment: @JohnFilleau how to do it?

Comment: what debugger do you have?

Comment: Don't really know it, never used before

Comment: Okay, well only you can answer that. Look up how to PAUSE your program via the debugger, and look up how to EDIT VARIABLE VALUES via the debugger. I can't help you if I don't know what you're using.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Do you have any C debugger recommendation?

Comment: There's probably one included in whatever IDE you're using. If you're just using gcc, then gdb is the canonical debugger. It's arcane, though, and you have to expect to put a good amount of time into learning how to use it. Don't try to rush through if you go that route.

Comment: ... but don't be scared of gdb. A handful commands will get you going: start, next (n) , step (s), print (p), quit (q).  When you get tired of navigated with s and n, you figure out they have a N argument, and  break (b) which allows you to automatically stop a given line or function and continue (c) goes the next break point.  Later you find b takes a condition.  When you tired of writing p all the time, you find out out about display (disp).  As @JohnFilleau, it goes deep, but it's worth learning.